# Should I recommend to delete a partial answer from a reputable external source?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing low quality answers and came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30542722). I chose to skip, as I don't know much (see anything) about [iOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS) development. It contains a direct copy and paste query and reply from Apple about a particular error.

It doesn't seem to truly answer the question, since it contains statements such as 'we suspect', but also appears to contain information that would be useful for others with the same issue.

Should this kind of answer be marked as low quality?

Comment: The answer seems to combine a question and a answer. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to leave it like that. Imho, everything except for the "Apple's reply" section should be part of the question instead of the answer.

Comment: "Should this kind of answer be marked as low quality?" - that's a very longwinded way of saying "downvote". Ambiguous too, quite a lot of people will read it as flagging it as VERY low quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your answer here.

> It doesn't seem to truly answer the question, since it contains statements such as 'we suspect' ...

If you believe the question isn't answered, then *downvote* it.  If you're feeling particularly generous, you could edit the post to remove the extra fluff from it and narrowly focus the answer, although I don't know what you'd be able to remove to be able to salvage an answer like this.